# In concept definitions, are substitution failures allowed outside of a requires expression?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts

Consider this code:

```
#include <type_traits>                                           
#include <iostream>

template <class T> concept bool C1 = std::is_same<T, int>::value; 

template <class T> concept bool C2 =  
    C1<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>; 

struct A {};                   

int main() { 
  std::cout << C2<int>; 
  std::cout << C2<A>;                                                 
  return 0;                                                           
}
```

GCC compiles it [fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xQC9StRPbGlHTV48) and prints 10.

But *§14.10.1.2 Predicate constraints [temp.constr.pred]* of [N4553](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4553.pdf) says

> A predicate constraint is a constraint that evaluates a constant expression E (5.19).

and then

> After substitution, E shall have type bool.

Since `C1<decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<A>())>` is a substitution failure, rather than having type bool, does that mean the program should be ill-formed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Concepts TS only defines behavior for determining the satisfaction of the associated constraints of a declaration; there's no provision for referring to a concept name outside of associated constraints. So strictly speaking, `std::cout << C<int>` and `std::cout << C<A>` are both ill-formed.

EWG decided in Kona to allow this as a new feature:

> Straw poll: SF | F | N | A | SA
>
> - Should we allow evaluation of concepts anywhere? 8 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 0
> - Should we allow the presence and evaluation of a requires-expression in any expression? 1 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 1
>
>   - Note that without the first poll, the second poll would change.

but there is no wording yet to specify its behavior.

GCC currently allows concepts-as-expressions as an (I believe undocumented) extension. I find it quite likely that this feature will be specified so that `C<X...>` evaluates to `false` when substitution of `X...` into the initializer of `C` fails to produce a valid expression, and otherwise has the value of the expression so obtained. That seems like the sane way to do this, and is consistent with the implementation in GCC.

Comment: What about this example? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QcfGmvtfaTvvLEM3 that only references the concept expressions from within the constraints. Would it be ill-formed under the current specification?

Comment: `f(T)`'s normalized constraint expression is `std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()), int>::value`. Substituting `A` for `T` doesn't produce an expression of type `bool` that evaluates to `true` as required by [temp.constr.pred]/1, so the constraint is not satisfied.

Comment: I admit it's both implicit and subtle that substitution failure is not an error in this case. You could submit an issue at github.com/cplusplus/concepts-ts if you think it needs clarification.